# string.Compare("ион", "йод") == 1

Tags: c#

Кто-нибудь может объяснить, почему это выражение истинно? При этом `string.Compare("и", "й") == -1`.

Вот такой тест у меня проходит в Visual Studio 2015:

```
[Test] public void WTF () {Assert.IsTrue (string.Compare("ион", "йод") > 0);}
```

Comment: нет, оно не истинно. добавьте больше кода и контекста

Comment: Врете вы все. И `String.Compare("и", "й")` и `String.Compare("ион", "йод"))` возвращают -1. Пруф: https://ideone.com/Kvh20N

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/655666/184217 - смотрите все ответы.

Comment: Проблема должна воспроизводиться только в русской локали.

Comment: @VladD аааа, то есть, вы думаете, что с "н" и "д" ТС просто опечатался? Тогда становится логично всё.

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, на уточнение ответа, который отмечен как дубликат этого. Я думаю, это разъясняет возможные отличия.