# Сравнение двух .txt

Tags: c#

Есть `1.txt и 2.txt`
в каждом есть около 10КК+ строк, но `==` длинны. Каким методом можно максимально быстро найти одинаковые строки из `1.txt` во втором, то есть найти те строки из `2.txt`, которые будут также в `1.txt`

```
1.txt
1 2 3 4 5 6 7  (пробел типа энтера)

2.txt
9 0 9 9 9 1
```

значит во втором только одно совпадение есть `"1"` ?

Comment: Если файл 1.txt влазит в память, просто считайте его в `HashSet<string>`.

Comment: @VladD знаю про этот HashSet... но он не годится т.к. в озу не влазит...мб еще чет?

Comment: Нужно найти одинаковые символы или строки?

Comment: А внешние утилиты можно использовать? Скажем, какой-нибудь `findstr`?

Comment: Как я понимаю, пример в вопросе не очень удачен - по тексту сравнивать надо строки равной длины, а в примере сравниваются отдельные символы. Также, как я понимаю, ВСЕ строки имеют равную длину - так что можно воспринимать файлы как наборы записей, причём позиционные. Тогда можно выполнить сортировку записей (строк) файлов (раз не лезет в ОЗУ - то слиянием), а затем выполнить сравнение (один проход, два указателя).

Comment: @Tode, 100 000 строк не влазит в ОЗУ? Не смешите, даже если это 100 000 строк по 100 символов, то это займет всего порядка 20 МБ. Если у вас нет 20 МБ, то у вас не то чтобы откомпилировать программу не получится, у вас Windows не запустится. Другой вопрос, если это, например, ограничение учебного задания...

Comment: Давайте определимся - вам нужно максимально быстро или всё же без загрузки всего в память, это вещи прямо противоположные

Comment: Сортировка строк в обоих файлах - это лучший и самый быстрый вариант. Можно распарсить строки из файлов в коллекцию, ваши 100к+ строк будут весить уже не так много. Затем провести сортировку и сравнивать двумя указателями по двум коллекциям снизу вверх. В третью коллекцию забивать совпадения, ну и делать с ними потом всё что заблагорассудится.

Comment: @Garrus_En строки отсортированны по алфавиту)....

Comment: @Tode ну тогда всё просто, открываете два файлстрима, и прогоняете параллельно по файлам два указателя, сравнивая значения, и постоянно подгоняя указатель на младшее значение к указателю на старшее значение

Comment: @Garrus_En я вашу мысль понял, гут, а что скажете если к примеру, строки такие параллельно, `1.txt` `aq3`(1-я строка) и `2.txt` `at1`(1-я строка)

Comment: @Tode тогда сравнивайте при помощи String.Compare(string,string). Метод возвращает целочисленное значение от -1 до 1. При "0" - строки равны(либо обе null). Если -1: Первая строка выше второй в порядке сортировки, Если 1: Первая строка ниже второй в порядке сортировки

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Если строки в файлах уже отсортированы, то задача значительно упрощается.

Воспользуемся итераторами:

```
var s1 = File.ReadLines("1.txt"); // Обратите внимание не ReadAllLines,
var s2 = File.ReadLines("2.txt"); //  а ReadLines
using (var en1 = s1.GetEnumerator()) // Берем
using (var en2 = s2.GetEnumerator()) //  итераторы
{
    if (en1.MoveNext() && en2.MoveNext())
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var w1 = en1.Current; // Берем по
            var w2 = en2.Current; //  элементу
            var comp = w1.CompareTo(w2);
            if (comp == 0) // Нашли совпадение
                Console.WriteLine(w1);
            if (comp <= 0) // Выбираем какой из указателей сдвинуть
                if (!en1.MoveNext()) break; // Выход если нечего больше брать
            if (comp >= 0)
                if (!en2.MoveNext()) break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Тоже самое, но работаем с потоками явно:

```
using (var sr1 = new StreamReader("1.txt"))
using (var sr2 = new StreamReader("2.txt"))
{
    var w1 = sr1.ReadLine();
    var w2 = sr2.ReadLine();
    while (w1 != null && w2 != null)
    {
        var comp = w1.CompareTo(w2);
        if (comp == 0)
            Console.WriteLine(w1);
        if (comp <= 0)
            w1 = sr1.ReadLine();
        if (comp >= 0)
            w2 = sr2.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

---

Примечания:

1. При сравнении строк много нюансов и если `CompareTo` вернул 0, то есть ненулевая вероятность того, что `Equals` или `==` покажут что строки не равны [Албахари, C# 6.0 Справочник: Полное описание языка, стр. 292].
2. Также, желательно, использовать компаратор, который был использован при сортировке строк, размещенных в файлах, так как разные компараторы могут давать разный результат [[Сортировка массивов русских символов и строк с участием буквы Ё](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/655887/218063)].

Comment: Знатное извращение, +1!

Comment: Неверно. Как минимум, перед вторым сравнением должно быть else, иначе может теряться равная строка. И вообще `w1` может оказаться null'ом и всё упадёт. А ещё, вероятно, есть косяк с повторяющимися равными строками.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да уже исправил баг. Просто else не подходит, так как при равных строках нужно двигать оба указателя. Завел временную переменную

Comment: А с повторяющимися непонятно что делать из условия, может достаточно один раз вывести. Но это уже тонкости, автор, надеюсь, справится сам с этим

Comment: @Андрей, даже если сдвинуть только один, то на следующей итерации будут неравны. А 3 сравнения вместо одного мне не нравятся. Лучше результат CompareTo сохранить в переменную.

Comment: @Андрей, так у него пример не отсортирован.

Comment: В комментариях выяснилось что сортирован: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706528/Сравнение-двух-txt/706723#comment1052924_706528

Comment: @Qwertiy, по поводу числа сравнений - согласен, главное не забывать что если Compare вернул 0 - не факт что строки равны...

Comment: @Андрей, почему же не факт?

Comment: @Qwertiy, метод
`CompareTo` применяет менее придирчивое сравнение, зависимое от культуры. Албахари, C# 6.0 Справочник: Полное описание языка, стр. 292

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63921/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-).