# Сортировка списка с учетом регистра list.Sort() - C#

Tags: c#

Сортировка списка с учетом регистра list.Sort() - C#

Не могу разобраться как сделать сортировку такого типа: Сначала все с заглавных букв по алфавиту, затем со строчных по алфавиту

**Изначально:**

fedor develop

Fedor Manager

Ivan manager

ivan Develop

Ivan Develop

ivan Manager

fedor Manager

Ivan Manager

Ivan develop

Fedor develop

**После сортировки:**

Fedor Manager

Fedor develop

Ivan Develop

Ivan Manager

Ivan develop

Ivan manager

fedor Manager

fedor develop

ivan Develop

ivan Manager

Comment: Используйте перегрузку [`List.Sort()` принимающую `IComparer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/234b841s(v=vs.110).aspx), сам comparer возьмите [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/655944/218063)

Comment: @Андрей: Тут в вопросе неестественная сортировка: сначала заглавные буквы.

Comment: @VladD, в моем компарере задаётся порядок вручную, можно настроить хоть z < a

Comment: @Андрей: Ну это да, но думаю, что как именно его настроить, ТС может и не сразу догадаться. И ещё у вас надо убрать `ToLowerInvariant` для целей ТС. (Кстати, а почему Invariant? а что с турецким `İ`?)

Comment: @VladD, вы не дочитали, там есть про то как изменить, если нужно всегда с учётом регистра. Вы никак с отпуска вернулись? :)

Comment: @Андрей: Точно, не дочитал :) Тогда подойдёт. // Вернулся :)

Answer (score 3):

Ну например так:

```
static int Compare(string l, string r)
{
    var commonResult = l.Zip(r, Compare).SkipWhile(n => n == 0).FirstOrDefault();
    return (commonResult != 0) ? commonResult : l.Length.CompareTo(r.Length);
}

static int Compare(char l, char r)
{
    var caseResult = char.IsUpper(r).CompareTo(char.IsUpper(l));
    return caseResult != 0 ? caseResult : l.CompareTo(r);
}
```

```
var s = new List<string>()
{
    "fedor develop", "Fedor Manager", "Ivan manager", "ivan Develop", "Ivan Develop",
    "ivan Manager", "fedor Manager", "Ivan Manager", "Ivan develop", "Fedor develop"
};
s.Sort(Compare);
```

Это сортирует ваш пример как надо (перемещает заглавные буквы вперёд), но поскольку вы не сформулировали требования на относительный порядок кириллицы и небуквенных символов, там возможны неожиданности.

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: @СергейБекмамбетов: Пожалуйста!