# datagridview sort c#

Tags: c#, winforms, сортировка, datagridview, текст

Проблема такая: нужно отсортировать данные в столбце, но они сортируются только по бинарным кодам, а мне нужно отсортировать текстовые данные в алфавитном порядке, мне сказали, что так может сортировать метод OrderBy, но как его прикрутить сюда я не знаю, да и неохота создавать лишнюю копию данных. Для сортировки текста нужно применить или региональные настройки языка, или создать дополнительную переменную в качестве контрольного значения. Как всё-таки это можно сделать?

Для русского языка, например, для контроля можно использовать строку "...еёж...", тем самым показывая где должна быть буква "ё", такая проблема есть в языках как на основе латиницы, так и на основе кириллицы. Привет создателям кодовых страниц.

Заполнение осуществляется методом for() dgv.Rows.Add(...); из листа структур.

Сортировать лист с исходными данными бесполезно, при первом тыке по заголовку в дгв произойдёт сортировка выбранной колонки и вся нужная мне последовательность строк собъётся на дефолтную по возрастанию или убыванию.

Попробовал использовать метот OrderBy на посмотреть перед загрузкой листа в дгв - чёт не то получается, что я хочу, почему-то маленькие буквы до больших независимо от игнора регистра при сравнении.

Comment: Что такое `datagridview`? Откуда этот компонент, из какой библиотеки? WinForms? Добавьте метку. Каким образом данные заносятся в этот грид: напрямую или с помощью привязки данных (data binding)? От этого зависит способ сортировки.

Comment: По поводу правильной сортировки смотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/655666/184217. Обязательно все ответы прочитайте.

Comment: А вот так не получится? Ну если у вас текстовые данные в листе

var list = new List<string>() { "Борис", "Юра", "Артур", "Иван"};
list = list.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();

В Вашем случае наверное будет OrderBy(x => x.текстовое поле)

Comment: Так, я вроде как написал сортировку строк по вхождениям подстрок, в принципе должно работать с любой дичью. Как теперь использовать это для сортировки отдельной колонки?

int IComparer<string>.Compare(string sz0, string sz1) { ... }

Comment: В настройках dgv можно запретить сортировку при клике по заголовку

Comment: я знаю, что сортировку колонок можно выключить в настройках, но мне она нужна

Comment: Опишите **конкретно**, какая именно сортировка нужна: по ежу или по игнору.

Comment: Если вы хотите именно в компоненте делать сортировку, то к чему вся писанина про лист, OrderBy и прочее?

Comment: Как прикрутить свой метод Compare к нужной колонке? В примерах, которые я нашёл везде используется жёсткое указание сортируемых колонок при нажатии левой кнопки, а не по клику в заголовке колонки.

Comment: Мне нужно прикрутить мой метод сортировки к отдельно взятой колонке в дгв, больше я ничего не знаю, просто пишу, что мне предлагали и что получается в результате.

Comment: а про лист я написал поскольку вы сами сказали, что нужно написать откуда данные берутся, хотя какая разница откуда они берутся я не понимаю

Comment: никто не поможет?